# Property doesn't exist on a union type

Tags: typescript

I have a problem with a union type:

At first, I define two interfaces:

```
export interface Action {
  type: string;

export interface ActionWithPayload<T> extends Action {
  payload: T;
}
```

Next, I define a few types and a union type for later usage:

```
export type LoadDrafts = Action;
export type LoadDraftsSuccess = ActionWithPayload<{ [K: string]: Draft }>;

export type DraftsActionsUnion =
  | LoadDrafts
  | LoadDraftsSuccess;
```

Finally, I use the union type inside my reducer function:

```
export const draftsReducer = (
  state = initialState,
  action: DraftsActionsUnion
): DraftsState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case DraftsActionsTypes.LoadDrafts: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    }
    case DraftsActionsTypes.LoadDraftsSuccess: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        loaded: true,
        entities: {
          ...state.entities,
          ...action.payload
        }
      };
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
```

And there is my problem - compiler complines that property `payload` doesn't exist on my union type (the `...action.payload` is causing this):

```
[ts]
Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'DraftsActionsUnion'.
  Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'Action'.
```

Dunno if it is a bug or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is your problem, "LoadDraftsSuccess" already extends "Action", thus cointaining both properties. You should probably remove the union type, and just use "LoadDraftsSuccess".

Comment: I think you are missing string literal values for your type discriminator field in your 2 action types. You’ll need this for your switch to discriminate which type is actually in the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing string literal values for your type discriminator field in your 2 action types. You’ll need this for your switch to discriminate which type is actually in the case block. There’s more than 1 way to do this, but here is a way you could do it.

```
export interface Action<K extends string> {
  type: K;
}

export interface ActionWithPayload<K, T> extends Action<K> {
  payload: T;
}

export type LoadDrafts = Action<‘loadDrafts’>;
export type LoadDraftsSuccess = ActionWithPayload<‘loadDraftSuccess’, { [K: string]: Draft }>;
```

This makes your type column a generic string literal that can be specified when inheriting your interfaces.

The important thing is for your type values to be string literals as opposed to strings so you get a finite set of values as opposed to effectively infinite string possibilities.

Comment: It helped, thanks. The `Action` interface actually comes from the `@ngrx/store` package, so I had to write a `SuperAction` interface myself.

Comment: FWIW you may not need to inherit the interface explicitly. TypeScript is structurally typed so your type will implicitly satisfy the interface if it has a type field with string content.